# jqTouch css and a href link

Tags: html, href, jqtouch

I am trying to call a link from a page which points to another part of the page.

This is the code I am using to do this:

```
<a href="#product"><img src="Dress1.jpg" alt="Pic1"></img></a>
```

The problem is that when I remove the css stylesheet links from the page, in other words:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqtouch/jqtouch.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="themes/jqt/theme.css">
```

It actually works but with the above links, it doesn't work.
Instead all it does is change the address (by adding #product) and doesn't display the image requested in

I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Thanks.
C.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which revision of jQTouch that you are using, you will need to add an animation class to your link like slide/flip/disolve in order to actually cause a transition from one psuedo page to the next.

```
<a href="#product" class="slide"><img src="Dress1.jpg" alt="Pic1"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do. in your example, the image is in the link, not the target div. from your description it sounds like you might want something like

```
<a href="#product">See my image</a>

<div id="product"><img src="Dress1.jpg" alt="Pic1"/></div>
```